# How many parameters are needed to specify a k-dimensional subspace of R^d?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the number $N^d_k$ of real-valued parameters that are needed to specify a k-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$? And how can these parameters be interpreted?

---

I know: $N^d_1 = N^d_{n-1} = d - 1 = \binom{d}{1} - 1$.

The parameters can be interpreted as the d components of a vector spanning the 1-dimensional subspace minus its (arbitrary) length.

I know: $N_1^3 = N^3_2 = 2 = \binom{3}{2} - 1$.

The parameters can be interpreted as two angles or as the three components of a normal vector of the 2-dimensional subspace minus its (arbitrary) length.

I know: $N^d_2 = N^d_{d-2} = \binom{d}{2} - 1$

I believe this, because a d-dimensional rotation has $\binom{d}{2}$ degrees of freedom, one for the rotation angle, the remaining $\binom{d}{2} -1$ ones for the (d-2)-dimensional (hyper)plane of rotation which also defines a 2-dimensional hyperplane as its orthogonal complement.

Question: How do I know that $\binom{d}{2}$ is the number of degrees of freedom of a d-dimensional rotation?

How can these $\binom{d}{2}$ parameters of a rotation or the $\binom{d}{2} - 1$ parameters of a 2-dimensional hyperplane be interpreted (maybe even intuitively)?

---

I guess that $N^d_k$, the number of parameters that are needed to specify a k-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$, is given by $\binom{d}{k} -1$. How can this be shown? Only formally by mathematical induction or more directly, using e.g. the observation, that there are $\binom{d}{k}$ k-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$ spanned by k of d elements of an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: As Joel points out below, you have to be really careful about using notions like "how many parameters..."  I interpret this question as "What is the dimension of the space of..." which is a more precise way of saying things.

Comment: At Ben's suggestion, I have turned my answer into a comment. There is a continuous map from R onto R^d for any d, by interleaving digits, and in this sense just one parameter suffices to specify a subspace, providing a continuous map from R onto the subspaces. I take this to show that one needs to be more precise about the sense of parameterization that is allowed or desired.

Comment: Could you please help me to clearify my concept of a "parameter" to make my question sensible. My concept of a "parameter" is something like a "degree of freedom" and is such that any 1-dimensional subspace has d-1 "degrees of freedom" (and corresponding to it its (d-1)-dimensional orthogonal complement). In Joel's interpretation my question patently does not make sense. Nor in Ben's interpretation: I am obviously not looking for the dimension of a k-dimensional subspace.

Comment: If you mean degree of freedom, then the k(n-k) count is the correct one. What you're generally doing is constructing some space X which aggregates all of the objects you are interested in (in this case, subspaces of a given dimension). If you are lucky, X is "nice" in some ways: maybe homogeneous, maybe has a smooth structure, etc. If X is sufficiently nice, it has the same dimension at each point. This dimension is a rigorous version of "degrees of freedom".

Comment: Thanks for taking my objecction seriously. Ben was suggesting that one look at the dimension, not of the individual subspaces, which are all k as you mention, but rather, the dimension of the collection of all subspaces, as a space of its own. How are we to think about this dimension? I suppose there is some kind of manifold structure here... 

Comment: Yes, Ben and I are both calculating the same thing: the dimension of the manifold Gr(k,n), the Grassmannian of k-dimensional subspaces of n-space.  It is indeed a manifold, and actually has a lot of nice additional structure.  For example, it is a homogeneous space (actually even better, a symmetric space).  So there is even a natural metric structure.

Comment: But what about my claim about the degrees of freedom of the d-dimensional rotation ($\binom{d}{2}$) minus 1 (the rotation angle) leaving the "degrees of freedom" of a (d-2)-dimensional hyperplane (the rotation plane)?

Comment: It isn't right: somewhat non-intuitively, a d-dimensional rotation doesn't have a (d-2)-dimensional axis of rotation.  The 2 and 3 dimensional cases don't give the whole picture.  For example, in R^4 you can have a rotation by 30 degrees in the XY plane and simultaneously 17 degrees in the ZW plane.  For a general rotation you have to split your space into a collection of orthogonal 2-planes and lines, and provide a rotation angle for each 2-plane.  The axis of rotation can therefore have any even codimension.

Comment: So what is the number of degrees of freedom of the d-dimensional rotation? We know: it's 3 for d=3.
Compared to the number of degrees of freedom of the (d-2)-dimensional hyperplane. We know: it's 2 for d=3.

Comment: What about the paper "General n-Dimensional Rotations" of Antonio Aguilera and Ricardo Pérez-Aguila, p. 4: "a general nD rotation is a rotation of an angle theta around a general (n-2)-dimensional subspace." Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  The closest true statement is that any arbitrary rotation in n-dimensions is a composition of rotations around (n-2)-dimensional subspaces.  For example, the rotation with matrix [[0,1,0,0],[-1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,-1,0]] in 4 dimensions has no  axis, but is the composition of two rotations of the form you describe.  The number of parameters is still n choose 2 since these special rotations generate the full group of rotations.  The object you are after here is the orthogonal group SO(n).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is similar to what Ben said about $d \times k$-matrices, but maybe a little more visual.  Instead of computing the dimension "as a whole", I'll just compute the dimension of subspaces neighboring a given one.

Take some fixed $k$-dimensional subspace $P$ with complementary space $P^\perp$ of dimension $n-k$.  Any sufficiently nearby subspace $P'$ to $P$ looks like a graph of a linear function $A : P \to P^\perp$.  And on the other hand, any such linear function defines a unique subspace.  So you only need to count linear maps from $P$ to $P^\perp$, which are $k(n-k)$-dimensional.

---

Thinking about the issue locally also helps avoid a mistaken dimension count like $n \choose k$.  The problem with the $n \choose k$ count is that you are enumerating some random points on the Grassmannian, which doesn't tell you anything about the dimension.  For example, take the case of 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  A subspace here is determined by its normal vector, so there is a bijection between 2-dimensional (oriented) subspaces and the unit sphere.
The $3 \choose 2$ planes in your count correspond to the north pole and two equatorial points $90^\circ$ apart.  But you wouldn't conclude that the sphere is 3-dimensional just because it has three points!

Answer (score 10):

The answer to this question is $k(d-k)$ "parameters" actually.  One way to make this formal is to say that the Grassmannian of k planes in $\mathbb{R}^d$  is a $k(d-k)$ dimensional manifold.

One way to think about this result is that generically, such a plane is the image a unique $d\times k$-matrix where the first $k\times k$ box is the identity matrix, leaving $k(d-k)$ entries you can choose freely.

You may want to look up some information on "Grassmannians" since there is much more detailed stuff out there on this question.

Comment: Oddly enough, the wikipedia page on Grassmannian doesn't mention the dimension explicitly, as far as I can see.

Comment: It gets very close to it at several points -- take a look at the example in the Schubert cell section where the euler characteristic of grassmanians is computed. 

Answer (score 3):

Let me expand a little on Ben's matrix remark, since all this talk about Grassmannians might give you the impression that the answer is complicated!  Any $d \times d$ matrix has a rowspace of dimension $k$, the row rank of the matrix.  You learned in linear algebra that

- row operations leave the rowspace of a matrix invariant, and
- up to row operations, every matrix has a unique representative in [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

I claim that this allows us to identify $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with rrefs with $k$ nonzero rows.  Why?  Because any two bases of a given space, when written down in matrix form, are related by row operations.

Now the rrefs with $k$ nonzero rows are exactly as Ben describes them: the $k \times k$ box in the upper left is the identity matrix and the $k(d-k)$ entries to the right of those can be chosen freely.  (The fancy term for this is called the "Schubert cell decomposition" of the Grassmannian.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more geometric way to find the answer. We can specify a $k$ dimensional subspace by giving $k$ vectors in that subspace. That would require $kn$ parameters, but we are overspecifying. By how much are we overspecifying? Write those vectors in a basis such that the first $k$ coordinates specify the location in the subspace, and the remaining $n-k$ coordinates specify the location orthogonal to the subspace. For specifying a subspace the $k$ coordinates within the subspace do not matter, since whatever values for those coordinates we choose, we get the same subspace. Therefore only the $n-k$ components of those $k$ vectors matter, so that's a total of $k(n-k)$ parameters.

In my opinion such a geometric argument gives far more insight than looking at reduced row echelon form matrices.